# SQL injection protection on the ASP.NET login control?

Tags: asp.net, sql-injection, login-control

How to SQL injection protection on the ASP.NET Login control? Does it contains protection againts SQL injection attack? Otherwise, how should I do?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET will automatically prevent injections through your inputs. 
If you have

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="true"></pages>
```

In your Web.Config you should be okay.

Update #:

You can also use add

```
<%@ Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" %>
```

to the top of your page

Comment: Thanks Harrison. But, I have a question. If ValidateRequest parameter value is false, is ASP.NET allow the HTML tags?

Comment: If you mark either as false it will assume that you do not want to validate possible injections or vulnerabilities in your code (which the compiler isn't always right. You may need to make an exception in your pages sometimes as I have found to bypass the system).

Comment: To add to this, I gave you the wrong Web Config property.

    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

That should do the trick if you wish to apply the protection to every page.

Comment: No problem at all my friend.

Answer (score 1):

the guy above has a great solution there are lots of ways of doing it 
you could also use store procedures and SQL will recognize the SQL injection and stop it

Comment: Also passing back integers can add a extra bit of security store procedures are 99.9% secure but if you still a little unsure about them passing back ints instead of string/nvarchar. Because if someone wanted to try SQL inject and then pass back a string to a int SQL will throw a error.

Answer (score 0):

Something I found recently that has helped me on my website.

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(Request.Form["somethingyouwantvalidating"], @"^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$"))
{
  the result is fine
}
```

I also found some HTML 5 attributes which may be helpful

```
pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+.{3,17}" 
title="Your Username must meet a length of 4-16 characters, letters and numbers only!"
```

Comment: Yes, I think also RegEx is the best way to validate values of some form elements. But I didn't know HTML 5 validation attributes. It looks useful. I will try it as soon as possible. Thanks.